# Syntax on Preg_match

Tags: php, mysql

I'm swapping a program out that is several years old, and updating the PHP, and MySQL deprication, and am getting jammed up on syntax for `preg_match` versus `ereg`.  I tried putting slashes everywhere, and cannot come up with the correct syntax.  What am I missing?

Old Line:

```
if (!$this->config_allow_src_above_docroot
    && !ereg('^'.preg_quote(str_replace($this->osslash, '/', realpath($this->config_document_root))), $AbsoluteFilename))
{
```

New Line:

```
if (!$this->config_allow_src_above_docroot
    && !preg_match('^'.preg_quote(str_replace($this->osslash, '/', realpath($this->config_document_root))), $AbsoluteFilename))
{
```

Please excuse my newb-ness, do I need to escape the '/'?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the delimiters that are required for the `preg_*` functions:

```
preg_match('#^'.preg_quote(str_replace($this->osslash, '/', realpath($this->config_document_root))) . '#', $AbsoluteFilename)
            ^                                                                                          ^
```

As I am using the `#`, there is no need to escape the forward slash.

Comment: Should this not work then?  if (!$this->config_allow_src_above_docroot && !preg_match(~'^'.preg_quote(str_replace($this->osslash, '/', realpath($this->config_document_root)))~,  $AbsoluteFilename)) {  using a tilde?  I'm getting PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: @SL0WLearner The delimiters are part of the regular expression string, you cannot add characters outside of the string.

Comment: Still telling me I have too many parens.  if (!$this->config_allow_src_above_docroot && !preg_match('~^'.preg_quote(str_replace($this->osslash, '/', realpath($this->config_document_root))).'~',  $AbsoluteFilename)) {

Comment: @SL0WLearner Maybe split it out instead of using a one-liner?